# What's the subtle differences between "pick up" and "pick out"?

Tags: differences

1. I have picked top 10 **out**  from these students.
2. I have picked top 10 **up**  from these students.

What's the subtle differences between "pick up" and "pick out"?

Comment: Neither one is idiomatic US English.

Comment: "I have picked out the top ten from these students."  "Pick out" means "select" or "remove".  "Pick up" means "lift from the table" or "hook up with at the bar".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no *subtle* differences because the difference is quite conspicuous.

To **Pick (something/someone) out** means according to [Cambridge - Pick Out](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pick-out-something-someone)

> To choose, find, or recognize something or someone in a group

*From all the puppies, we picked out the smallest one to take home.*
*We could pick our parents out easily in the old photos.*

That is to select or recognize someone/something from a group.

To **Pick (something) Up** means according to [Merriam-Webster Pick Up](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pick%20up)

> to take hold of and lift up. *picked up all the pieces*

Pick up can mean a lot of things depending on usage. Another particular
usage is

> to acquire by study or experience.
>   *Picking up a great deal of knowledge in the process*

Your second sentence doesn't express the same meaning as the first.
*I have picked **the** top 10 up from these students.* In fact this sentence sounds a bit strange. As *@DJClayworth* pointed out in his answer this might mean to physically *life them up*. You can also *pick people up* in vehicles. But *pick up* doesn't mean *selecting from a group.*

In fact, I wouldn't use *Pick Out* in your example sentence as well.

I would rather write it as:

*I have identified the (best performers, athletes etc) from these students.*

*Single Out* is also a good choice, but it has a slightly negative connotation.

*I have singled out 10 students for punishment*

Answer (score 1):

To "pick something up" means to physically or metaphorically lift it. It can also be used to mean collecting for transportation or similar, or to hook up romantically.

To "pick something out" means to select it from a group of things, or to detect or identify it.

The two are not interchangeable.

The normal version of your sentence would be

> I have picked out the top ten from these students.

The definite article is normal. "I have picked the top ten out from these students" would also be acceptable. If you said "I have picked up the top ten students" it would mean you were lifting them or taking them on a date.